# Log Keras metrics for each batch as per Keras example for the loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss

In the Keras doc, there is an [example](https://keras.io/guides/writing_your_own_callbacks/#a-basic-example) where a custom callback is created to log the **loss** for each batch. This has worked fine for me, however I also want to log metrics that I add.

For example for this code:

```
optimizer = Adam()
loss = losses.categorical_crossentropy
metric = ["accuracy"]

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss=loss,
              metrics=metric)


class LossHistory(Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.losses = []

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        self.losses.append(logs.get('loss'))

loss_history = LossHistory()

history = model.fit(training_data, training_labels,
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    verbose=2,
                    validation_data=(val_data, val_labels),
                    callbacks=[loss_history])
```

I can't figure out how to get access to the metrics.

Comment: Note that, as it's possiblle to see in the final part of the basic example linked, that will not return the loss for each batch but the average loss at the end of that batch. For example at batch 3 the loss that will be reported is the loss of that batch averaged with the previous two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metric history is stored inside `loss_history.losses`:

```py
def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
  self.losses.append(logs.get('loss'))
```

This method will get called at the end of every batch and just appends the loss metrics into `self.losses` so once training has completed you can just access this list directly with `loss_history.losses`.

I should also add that if you wanted to include accuracy, for example, you could also do something like:

```py
class LossHistory(Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.losses = []
        self.accuracy= []

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        self.losses.append(logs.get('loss'))
        self.accuracy.append(logs.get('accuracy'))
```

then subsequently access it with:

`loss_history.accuracy`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, what if the metric was something more like "tf.keras.losses.mape"? Could i then do the same but with logs.get(tf.keras.losses.mape) ? or how would that be stored?

Comment: you could do `logs.get('mape')` as long as `tf.keras.losses.mape` was passed in to `model.compile()` in the array of metrics

Comment: or alternatively if you use `tf.keras.losses.mape` as your loss function then you can just proceed as before with `logs.get('loss')` but (I think) you mean as an *additional* metric, right?

Comment: yes I mean as a metric, so for example metric mape and loss mse, because mape can be interesting to look at but not ideal for a loss function. I'll try this now and tick your post as an answer, thanks a lot

Comment: logs.get("accuracy") doesn't work I think it needs "acc" for some reason, going to try it again with that, as well as "mape".

Comment: should work with whatever label the metric has in your log messages. this type of thing: `Epoch 1/1000
64/64 [==============================] - 272s 4s/step - loss: 0.1836 - accuracy: 0.3647 - precision: 0.0130 - recall: 0.6414 - f1: 0.0250`

Comment: if it's showing in these messages then you should be able to use the label so, in the above example,  I could choose from `accuracy`, `recall`, `f1`, etc